# How do I programmatically remove unwanted user settings?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm currently using the example from MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171565%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to save user configuration settings.

This works fine for my needs as the number of objects I need to store may differ from run to run. Since the user can create or destroy objects at will I need to track those and update the settings file accordingly. I use a SettingsKey to read/write each object since the properties between objects may differ. Each object has a unique id that I use in the SettingsKey.

What I have observed is this: each object is saved and restored properly. However when an object is destroyed it remains in the settings file.

I need to remove the destroyed objects from the settings file.
How is this done? I haven't been able to find any code examples that show how to do this.

These are declared earlier in the code: 
    UserSettings uSet;
    uSet = new UserSettings();

Here's the code that saves the objects:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < CurrrentViewportCount; i++)  
    {  
        if (VP_ID[i] != -1)  
        {  
            uSet.SettingsKey = "Viewport" + VP_ID[i];  
            foreach (Control cP in this.Controls)  
            {  
                if (cP.Name.Equals(uSet.SettingsKey) == true)  
                {  
                    Viewport VP = (Viewport)cP;  
                    uSet.PanelName = VP.Name;  
                    uSet.PanelID = VP.PanelID;  
                    uSet.ConnectionName = VP.SourceMRL;  
                    uSet.Save();  
                    break;  
                }  
            }  
        }  
        else  
        {  
            //  Need to remove unused object  
        }  
    }
```

I apologize for the formatting (indentation) if it's off. This is my first post and I tried following the guidelines for posting code....

I have considered deleting the user.config file and reloading but I have the feeling that a Reload() will only recreate the user.config from the app.exe.config and not present me with an "empty" user.config file.

To recap, my main question is how do I remove specific user settings?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you only saving one viewport at a time?

Comment: Without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem, it's difficult if not impossible to know exactly the best answer. That said, if the problem you are having is that the API itself isn't providing you a fine-grained enough control over the contents of the actual file, you probably need to wrap your storage of individual objects in a serialized collection, so that you can explicitly remove them as necessary (i.e. the whole collection will be stored, in its exact state...removed objects won't be present).

Comment: I'm saving all viewports on the FormClosing event.

Comment: Thanks for the help with the formatting!

Comment: @Peter Duniho: The code I provided I felt was adequate to describe the solution I'm using as there are many other solutions out there. This solution seemed to be easiest and quickest to implement. The issue is how to remove the no longer needed data without completely reworking the code. Since I'm new to this I'd appreciate any suggestions as to what I need to post in addition to what I posted for it to be a good, minimal, complete code example. Thanks!

Comment: People posting questions _always_ feel the code they included was adequate, whether or not it actually is. The link I provided explains what "adequate" actually looks like. The best way for you to get help is to make sure that people reading your question and considering what an answer would be do not have to recreate large swaths of your code just to get a runnable example to test. No one's going to kick you off Stack Overflow if you don't comply, but at the same time you may find the number of people willing to even think about your question is small if you provide an inadequate code example

Comment: I think I see what's happening here. My intent/expectation was to provide enough information so that someone who is familiar with the saving and retrieving of user settings would see what I was doing and be able to say without creating an application, "you need to use this (API/method/??) and do this and that...".

Comment: I think the approach you're taking is to create an application from the code I supplied in order to programmatically try/test different ways to help find a solution. Unfortunately for me at this time, I'd have to spend time that I'm very short supply of to provide the bare minimum of code you'd require, hence my hope of an easy quick answer. I do appreciate your willingness to help and your feedback so far. I do agree with just about all you have stated as I have been frustrated in finding a possible solution only for it to incomplete.